# Is there a word to describe someone who has healthy eating habits but isn't necessarily fit or muscular?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who eats healthy.  I'm not looking for general reflections of physical health like "fit" or "in shape" or "healthy".  I'm looking for something that specifically calls out dietary quality - nutritional is the best I can come up with but that seems wrong / awkward.

Edit - to clarify intent, I'm allowing characters in a lifestyle simulator to demonstrate competency across various factors.  These are phrased as adjectives.  Others include:

- Physically Fit
- Disciplined
- Energetic
- Committed
- (having a healthy diet?)
- Hygienic
- etc

Comment: I've only ever heard such people referred to as "healthy eaters". If there's a single word to describe these people, I'd love to learn it as well!

Comment: "Well nourished" would work, but is not a single word. A single word is unlikely.

Comment: Please see this advice from management: [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085)

Comment: @tchrist note that that merely [points out the _tools at our disposal_](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity#comment4321_2160) (i.e. close voting) to get rid of the question deemed unsuitable. As it is, the question has no down votes, multiple answers from seasoned SE users and no close votes. As it is, I think the question also passes the three questions in bold at the end of the Meta post: the user did their research, it didn't yield a satisfying answer and the question might be interesting to future visitors.

Comment: @user666 - Pinging you here as it seems unfair on Kata's answer. I wouldn't judge a site on the basis of a response from a new user. New users' answers often fall below the standard expected on a site. Your comment on her answer is close to the line regarding the Be Nice policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nutritionally aware**, while not listed by any dictionary I could find, I did find it [in some books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22nutritionally+aware%22). It seems to describe the mindset of being aware of food (or more generally: nutrient) intake, rather than actually eating healthy (you can know what's healthy and still have a bad diet).

Answer (score 0):

*Salubrious* is "healthy," but it doesn't really describe the mindset of the individual. Right now, the closest that I can recommend that would be of a positive frame of mind is "clean-eating," but that probably isn't exactly what you're looking for, since it has a [very specific connotation](http://www.vogue.co.uk/article/what-is-clean-eating):

> Clean eating was a term that emerged from this movement, arguably initially used to describe fresh, nutrient-rich food cooked from scratch.

On the other hand, there *is* a term for taking this too far: *orthorexic* is a term for people whose obsession with eating healthy becomes a disorder.

Answer (score -1):

In its synonym discussion for *wholesome*, Merriam-Webster Unabridged states:

> *healthful*, *wholesome*, *salubrious*, *salutary* mean favorable to the health of mind or body.
>
> *healthful* implies a positive contribution to a healthy condition.

And it gives an example:

> A *healthful* diet.

So someone who eats a healthy diet can be described as a *healthful* eater. If the context is clear, the adjective in your simulator can simply be *healthful*.

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend a term ***dietary*** or ***dietary intake***, based on this explanation:

[What is a dietary intake?](https://ods.od.nih.gov/Health_Information/Dietary_Reference_Intakes.aspx)

Recommended Dietary Allowance (RDA): average daily level of intake sufficient to meet the nutrient requirements of nearly all (97%-98%) healthy people.

Answer (score -2):

*salubrious* is the closest, but no one would get your point.
Is there a specific reason you need this for?

if it's for a story, you could just use *vegan* and give him saggy moist skin and bad posture.

Comment: Is this really the level of quality I can expect from this SE site?  Your second comment was completely unnecessary and helps nobody.  I've added some context to my question to address your question.

Comment: What does "salubrious" mean? Why is it appropriate here? Please add some references/citations and explanation.

Answer (score -3):

Glutton or Gourmand is the word you are looking for.
Gourmand means a food lover and glutton(excessively greedy eater) is used in an over-ly sense and mostly in negative terms.

Comment: **I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who eats healthy.**